# Using normalizer with ReduxForm results in form always being dirty

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using a normalizer to convert ISO 8601 date/time values (*e.g* `2016-05-24T20:38:34+00:00`) coming from a rest api to simply a date (*e.g* `2016-05-24`). My normalizer looks like this:

```
export const dateNormalizer = function(value){
    if(value)
        return moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    };
```

I also use a normalizer for currency conversion (*e.g.* making sure it's only numbers, etc).

The problem I'm facing is that this is causing the form to *always* be dirty. In other words, as soon as the initial state is loaded (via `initialValues` in `mapStateToProps`) `this.props.dirty` always returns true. Even dispatching a `reset` doesn't result in `dirty=false`.

Is there a way to overcome this? The issue I'm having is that I want to be able to display a warning to the user that they're about to abandon their changes without having to implement my own `onChange` override for each input field, and right now they're *always* warned about abandoned changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wasn't able to find a solution using the `normalizer` framework built in to ReduxForm. Instead, I took [this suggestion from the issues list](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/376) and built my own mask/normalizer component to adjust the values before they're displayed, but also make sure the store gets the raw values. This also has the added benefit of letting me do things like represent currency as a `Number` internally but as a `String` (with a `$` and thousands separators) in the ui. Here's the code in case anybody ends up wanting to do something similar:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const isSupportedType = (type) => {
    return type !== 'checkbox' && type !== 'file' && type !== 'select-multiple';
};

class MaskedInput extends Component {

    normalize(value, mask, normalize, originalBlur, originalChange){
        return {
            value: mask(value),
            onBlur: (event) => {
                if (isSupportedType(event.target.type)){
                    originalBlur(normalize(event.target.value))
                }else{
                    originalBlur(event);
                }

            },
            onChange: (event) => {
                if (isSupportedType(event.target.type)){
                    originalChange(normalize(event.target.value));
                }else{
                    originalChange(event);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    render(){

        const {
            mask,
            normalizer,
            value,
            onBlur,
            onChange,
            ...rest
            } = this.props;

        return <input {...rest} {...this.normalize(value, mask, normalizer, onBlur, onChange)} />
    }

}

MaskedInput.propTypes = {
    mask: React.PropTypes.func,
    normalizer: React.PropTypes.func
};

export default MaskedInput;
```